# Can I visit the USA twice in a year with an ESTA

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, repeat-visits

I visited my best friend in California this winter. It was the first time I ever visited the USA and I stayed for 70 days. I've been back in my country for a month and a half and I've decided to return to the US a two-week visit, leaving in a few days.

I've booked the tickets but now I'm worried about returning the US so soon. I'm 19 and I have to start college in August. I don't plan on living in the US, just  I just want to have fun with my friends before I'm stuck for 4 years having to study.

I'm scared I'll be denied entry, andd my vacation will be ruined.

I plan on only taking a backpack with me with outfits for a week. I've read it can cause problems to travel with few belongings; I just don't think I need more.

And I plan on having $800 cash with me; will that be enough?

Comment: $800 cash is plenty of cash to physically carry (I don't generally advise carrying that much cash anyway), but there's no requirement that you have cash with you; the requirement is that you're able to support yourself. Is the $800 all the money you have in the world or will you have access to more funds through a bank account?

Comment: Did you tell them you were staying 70 days when you entered last time? The only issue I can imagine arising is if you told them you were going to stay for significantly less than the 70 days and they recorded that answer, as that might make them doubt the 2 weeks you are claiming this time. I doubt they would refuse entry even for this, but they might give you a hard time and maybe limit you to time requested (so don't low-ball that). The answer is correct, there is no reason to expect a problem, but they have discretion they might exercise if they have a reason to not believe you.

Comment: No ill have my credit card but I've heard I needed plenty of cash on me so I got some. I told them I'd stay 70 days for my first trip I left on the date I had on my tickets when I arrived. I'm just worried because I'm going back after such little time in my country and it seems to be a problem for a lot of people

Comment: @meganmenef - From memory of another question on this site (I can't find it now, and unfortunately it's not the one I've linked above) the general rule that CBP officials follow is that you a "reasonable" amount of time between visits is the same length as your visit. If you visited the US for 70 days, and will have been back in the UK for 50 days before trying to visit again, you'll be stretching the (unofficial) limit.

Comment: What you therefore need is good evidence that you'll be going back to the UK. *Take a copy of your college acceptance letter with you* - you might need it to convince the CBP official that a) you're definitely coming back to the UK and b) this will probably be your last trip for a while.

Answer (score 5):

An ESTA allows you to visit for 90 days maximum in one visit.

Leaving the country ends that visit and will reset the clock when you return and you can therefore return for up to 90 days, unless you went to Canada, Mexico or the Caribbean, which are all counted as not having left and the clock on the original 90 days will still be running. (any time spent in those countries counts as time in the US)

You also cant keep doing it.. the purpose of an ESTA is for occasional travel. Twice should be fine though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your [passport is valid and you have a visa, or are from a country that participates in the Visa Waiver Program](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1072/kw/multiple%20entry%20with%20esta/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ4OTA4NzA3NS9zaWQvdXBRcEg3ZG4%3D), you should not be denied entry to visit the US.

According to [US Customs and Border Protection](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1126/kw/multiple%20entry%20with%20esta/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ4OTA4NzA3NS9zaWQvdXBRcEg3ZG4%3D):

> Your ESTA authorization is generally valid for multiple trips over a
>   period of two years (starting the date that you are approved) or until
>   your passport expires, whichever comes first*.

The * refers to:

> *If you obtain a new passport or change your name, gender or country of citizenship, you will be required to apply for a new travel
>   authorization. This is also required if one of your answers to any of
>   the VWP eligibility questions changes.  The associated fee of $14 will
>   be charged for each new application submitted.